# Multiplayer flash games

Tags: flash, multiplayer, flash-cs6

How to enable multiple key press detection in adobe flash professional cs6.
(basically making a multi-player game)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use gamepad or other outer-joystick to second player, and read a littlemore on tech forums example [leferonato.com/](http://leferonato.com/) or [here](http://www.gotoandplay.it) in the forums you can found some answare. If its under maintrance use the common phrase... "[g00gl](https://www.google.hu/search?q=flash%20multi%20keypress&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-US%3aofficial&client=firefox-a&channel=fflb) is your friend..." but the direct actionscript answare [here](http://www.freeactionscript.com/tag/flash-multiple-key-press-detection/) and [here](http://www.freeactionscript.com/2009/02/multiple-key-press-detection/) and [here](http://www.kirupa.com/forum/showthread.php?350549-Reliable-AS3-multiple-keypress) and here.

Answer (score 1):

It isn't something you "enable". You simply code it.

```
if(Key.isDown(65)) //"a"
    ;//move 1st player left
if(Key.isDown(Key.LEFT)) //left arrow
    ;//move 2nd player left
```

But you should note that keyboards are [horrible](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rollover_%28key%29#Key_blocking_and_ghosting) at handling multiple key presses at the same time. You will notice that many 3 key combinations don't work at all or register the wrong keys.